# Please Help In Windows Form Calculator

Tags: c#

I am beginner and I have made calculator in C# (Windows Forms) and only one problem occur so plz help me.

Problem is that when I divide 0 / 0 = then my code crashes on this line

```
m_res /= decimal.Parse(m_store[i + 1].ToString());

else if (m_store[i].ToString() == "/")
{
    //Textbox.Text = "";
    m_res /= decimal.Parse(m_store[i + 1].ToString());
    TextBox2.Text = m_res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You can't divide by zero.  In any language. Or math, for that matter.  How do you divide something by nothing?  Add a check to see if the value is 0 and alert the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you probably want is

```
decimal div;
decimal.TryParse(m_store[i + 1].ToString(), out div);
if(div != null && div != 0)
   m_res /= div;
```

Its fundamental maths that defines that nothing can be divided by 0

**EDIT**: Not tested this but I presume it will work and be more efficient

```
decimal div;
if(decimal.TryParse(m_store[i + 1].ToString(), out div) && div != 0)
   m_res /= div;
```

Comment: Why would the second block of code be more "efficient"?

Comment: @Cody Gray - its more efficient as you only have to check the result of tryparse once instead of twice

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot divide by zero ever.

Try something like:

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse(m_store[i + 1].ToString());
if (d.Equals(0))
    MessageBox("Cannot divide by zero");
else
    mres /= d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip:

> To avoid the divide by zero exception, you obviously must check the
>   denominator against the zero value.

And:

> This numeric check will be much faster than having an exception thrown
>   in the runtime.